# Joining three tables based on only one key

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi Good day everyone,

### table_1

```
id       c2
-----------
id4     5     
id1     5
id3      4
id2     4
```

table_2

```
-----------
id       c1
-----------
id1      5     
id2      5
id3      4
id4      4
```

table_3

```
-----------
id       c1
-----------
id3      5     
id1      5
id2     4
id4      4
```

After joining these three tables , I would to get as the following table.
target

```
----------------
id       c1c2c3
----------------
id1      555     
id2      544
id4      454
id3      445
```

If you don't mind help me , please.But my tables have only one unique key.My database is mysql 5.1.

Comment: which is the unique key between the three tables?

Comment: Will all IDS be in all tables? What if an ID is missing from one or two tables? Also it is a little difficult to follow: You have `c1` twice, table1 has c2, table2 c1, etc.

Comment: sorry fri, in table 3 column is c3 not c1.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT T1.ID,concat(T2.c1,T1.c2,T3.c3 ) AS C1C2C3
FROM Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2 On T1.id =T2.id JOIN Table3 T3 On T3.id =T1.id
ORDER BY RIGHT(T1.ID,1)
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a6bc8/3)**

---

**O/P:**

---

```
id       c1c2c3
----------------
id1      555     
id2      544
id3      445
id4      454
```

Comment: You could also do an impcliciet join by something like `where T1.id =T2.id and T3.id =T1.id` but this depends a little on type of join you need.

Comment: @frlan There is no difference apart from syntax. The queries would return EXACTLY the same thing.

Comment: Thank you Fluffeh , I got it.But I've more added " Group by id " , because in my dataset there may be more than one key is contian in field  "id" .

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, concat(t2.c1,t1.c2,t3.c3 ) as 'c1c2c3' from table_1 t1 inner
join table_2 t2 inner join table_3 t3 on t2.id=t1.id 
and t3.id=t1.id and t3.id=t2.id order by c1c2c3 desc
```

Comment: I got that. Thank you so much.